# iOS background download HLS stream

Tags: ios, background, nsurlsession, http-live-streaming

I want to download HLS stream file in background.

I first download the `m3u8`-file and parse it to get many urls (about 30 ~ 200). Then I create a background session. Last, for every url, I create a `NSURLSeessionDownloadTask`, I create next task and download after the former one finished.

It works well when the app is in foreground. But in background, it stoped and not create new task after the current one finished.

So, How can I download the urls one by one in background? (I don't think play music in background to keep app active is a good idea)

Comment: Do you have appropriate background modes specified in your app's Info.plist file?  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Surely,I use the mode "App downloads content from the network"

Comment: Assuming you're actually playing the HLS stream, you'll probably want "audio" mode.  That said, I doubt this is the problem.  I'm assuming this isn't happening in an extension or anything (with a separate plist)....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create all of the tasks once the download began, and it seems to work.

Comment: That's okay as long as there are only a few parts.  At some point, you're going to run into issues with the app misbehaving (really slow downloads, IIRC) from having too many tasks in a single session.  I'm not sure where the exact point is, but I do know that folks have run into it.